# text width is limited by image

Tags: html, css, text

In my website, I have an image with text beneath it. The text width is limited by the 100px width of the image above it. I would prefer the text width be independent from the image width. Here is my code.

html:

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="customizing text-center">

    <span class="process-icon icustomize">&nbsp;</col>
        <h4>Customizing</h4>
        <p class="text-center">We create custom 
            there is random text here.</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Read More</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.process-icon{

  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: transparent url(img/process-sprite.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: top left;
}
```

Comment: It's not an image that's limiting the width; You have a width attribute in your CSS rule. What is it that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I think the problem is that you haven't an end tag for the `<span>`.

Comment: I have 4 images in a row that are 100px side by side (400px total). The images are spread across the page and each new icon is shifted by -100px -200px and -300px to have each different icon appear. I have text beneath each icon but i want the text to be wider than the icon presented.

Comment: Give us an example of your full code and also an example of exactly what you're trying to achieve (an image possibly).

Comment: Can you give a sample pleasE?

Comment: I had changed to a <span> tag from a <col> tag which I still had a </col>. Silly coding error on my behalf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set the width value, so it is not the image that is causing this. As mentioned in the comments you have not closed your `"<span>"` tag correctly.

Add

`</span>`

That will fix the text to be aligned underneath the image and then change the following in your code.

```
    width: 100px;

    To

    width: 100%;   //can be whatever you need
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lo4avzye/)